# MGTwitterEngine error: yajl/yajl_parse.h no such file or directory

Tags: mgtwitterengine, yajl

I'm using MGTwitterEngine in my project and when compiling the whole project I get 23 error which are all releated to `yajl/yajl_parse.h no such file or directory`

Is there any solution for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project only contains references to yajl. You have to plug it in by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: Hi tob, I've same error how can i reslove this may you provide some steps/code thanx in advance